# Noscript command adds BRs/Ps although it shouldn't

Tags: javascript, html

I have the following lines of code:

```
<div id="icons_js" style="visibility:hidden;"><a href="#gototop" title="Seitenanfang"><img src="img/toparrow.png" class="icons" border="0"></A>&nbsp;&nbsp;<a href="biografie_de.php" title="zurück"><img src="img/leftarrow.png" class="icons" border="0"></a></div>
<noscript>test</noscript>
```

The div is hidden and is only made visible if the user scrolls...everything is ok with JS enabled, but if disabled, the noscript command not only outputs "test", but adds BRs or Ps between text in my content div and the bottom of content. The div "icons_js" does not even have any BRs or Ps.

What is missing?

The site is https://www.seelenpuls.at/update11/biografie_info_de.php btw...

[image: Screenshot]

Update: Added a screenshot...ok, seems there are no BRs/Ps added, but as the div is hidden and only made visible with JS, I thought the icon images in the div would not create space between the text and the bottom of the div. How can I switch the entire div from being processed if JS is disabled? I tried script tags around it, but then the script related (not posted here) to the div no longer worked.

Comment: I doubt that very much. Do you really see them in the element inspector in DevTools?

Comment: When I use View Source I see `<p>` and `<br>` inside `<div id="content"`. So they're not being added, they're already there.

Comment: Added a screenshot...ok, seems there are no BRs/Ps added, but as the div is hidden and only made visible with JS, I thought the icon images in the div would not create space between the text and the bottom of the div.

Comment: Putting `<noscript>` on a new line adds whitespace between the divs.

Comment: How is this anything to do with PHP? Please remove the PHP tag.